# Mixpanel Javascript - distinct_id variable returning an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, mixpanel

I'm trying to set up Mixpanel People tracking on my registration form, but I'm unable to pass Mixpanel's `distinct_id` to my form.

This is the script that gets the user's distinct_id from Mixpanel ([documentation](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.get_distinct_id)):

```
mixpanel.init("MY_TOKEN", {
    loaded: function(mixpanel) {
        distinct_id = mixpanel.get_distinct_id();
    }
});
```

When I try to pass it to a hidden input in my registration form with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#distinct_id").val(distinct_id);
});
```

to `<input type="hidden" name="distinct_id" id="distinct_id" value="" />`, the resulting line in the source code in Chrome Inspector just looks like this: `<input type="hidden" name="distinct_id" id="distinct_id" value="[object HTMLInputElement]">`

Yet, when I do `console.log(distinct_id);` in the Chrome console, it outputs the ID.

I'll admit that my javascript is pretty rubbish, so I could be missing something obvious here... I've tried parsing it with the `JSON.stringify` function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    distinct_id = JSON.stringify(distinct_id, null, 4);
    $("#distinct_id").val(distinct_id);
});
```

but it just produced `{}` as a value in the form...

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a quote missing in the first code block.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks. Must have deleted that when I removed my Mixpanel token for this question

Comment: It might be that the  `ready` callback triggers before `pixpanel.init...loaded` callback, if would be better to move that little `$(document).ready` block *inside* the `init....loaded` callback.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log` the id you get, right after `get_distinct_id`? Is `distinct_id` defined as a global variable?

Comment: Have you tried strait js: `document.getElementById('distinct_id').value = distinct_id;` without the `stringify` and put this inside the mixpanel `init - loaded`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have shared it looks likes right now you are treating the variable "distinct_id" as a global variable when it is actually only within the scope of the init function. As trincot mentioned, moving what you have in the `$(document).ready()` block might solve the issue, though declaring distinct_id as a global variable should also work.

Answer (score 0):

So as per the suggestion by @trincot, I added the `$("#distinct_id").val(distinct_id);` to the `init ... loaded` function, and it worked.

As a reference, here's what the resulting code looks like:

```
mixpanel.init("MY_TOKEN", {
    loaded: function(mixpanel) {
        distinct_id = mixpanel.get_distinct_id();
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#distinct_id").val(distinct_id);
        });
    }
});
```

Additionally, you can skip the `$(document).ready(function() {});` entirely and just do this, as you only need mixpanel to load:

```
mixpanel.init("MY_TOKEN", {
    loaded: function(mixpanel) {
        distinct_id = mixpanel.get_distinct_id();
        $("#distinct_id").val(distinct_id);
    }
});
```